# How to create boolean array in global - Java

Tags: java

I want create Boolean array in global, here code i tried to make

```
public class BettingHandler extends BaseClientRequestHandler
{
  public static int player[]  = new int [100];
  public static int i;
  public static boolean playerAct[];

  public void handleClientRequest(User user, ISFSObject params)
     {
        RouletteExtension gameExt = (RouletteExtension) getParentExtension();
        if (BettingHandler.player[BettingHandler.i] != -1)
        {
            trace("player problem");
            BettingHandler.player[BettingHandler.i] = user.getPlayerId();
            BettingHandler.playerAct[BettingHandler.i] = true;
            i++;
        }
        trace("If this showed, no error");
     }
}
```

In Eclipse not showed redcross sign in left this code

```
public static boolean playerAct[];
```

and here

```
BettingHandler.playerAct[BettingHandler.i] = true;
```

I make this for handler in SFS2X, so i check error in SFS2X zone monitor but unfortunately, this script just run till this

```
trace("player problem");
```

when remove this code

```
BettingHandler.playerAct[BettingHandler.i] = true;
```

script run till this

```
trace("If this showed, no error");
```

so i know something wrong with `BettingHandler.playerAct[BettingHandler.i] = true;`, How could I fix my code?

Comment: Initialize the array before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing:

```
public static int player[]  = new int [100];
public static int i;
public static boolean playerAct[];
```

The first array, there you actually create an array for 100 elements.
You omit that step for your second array. And you are really surprised that the second gives you problems?

Besides: whatever framework your are working with; maybe you should first step back and learn some more about the basics of Java. For example, the above code might work when fixed; but doing everything with public static variables ... looks very much like bad design.

Comment: Haha, sry i miss it, honestly it's first time for me in Java and stil learning to develop game from cocos2d-js and now my 4th month, so i learn javascript, but my mentor said that game must can multiplayer, and using SFS2x where serverside using Java. i think i just distracted by suddenly change languange programing. Yeah it's better if I'm learning basics of Java first, thanks @GhostCat

Comment: All the more reasons to be careful! Thing is: if there will be really multiple players .. could it be at some point, that your server will be running more than one thread? If so, using global static has potential of a lot problems (as you will need a lot of locking to get things thread-safe!)

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized the array but you are trying to use it.

```
  public static boolean playerAct[] = new boolean[100];
```